# ${a_n}$is the number of series of length $n$ on $\{a,b,c\}$ where $b$ must be before $c$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

${a_n}$ is the number of series of size $n$ on $\{a,b,c\}$ where $b$ must be before $c$.

So I started by saying that for $f_1$ we get $f_1 = 3$, because only $(a,b,c)$ is allowed. For $f_2$ we get $f_2 = 3$, because only $(ab,ba,bc)$ are allowed.

Then I need to solve for $f^n = x^n$ which means:

$f_n = 2f_{n-1} + f_{n-1}$ which yields $x^2 - 2x - 1 = 0$, from here I got that the $x_1,x_2$ contains $\sqrt{(\text{number})}$.  I mean they are not over $\mathbb Z$, they are over $\mathbb Q$, is it okay? And if so, did I solve it right up to now?

I know that I need to find after it $a,b$ that solve $f^n = a(\text{number})^n + b(\text{number})^n$ with $f_1$ and $f_2$.

edit: $c$ can be the first in the series. and $'b'$ must be immediate before $'c'$. which means, maybe, that: $f^n = 3f_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: How did you deduce $f_n=2f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$?

Comment: What does "$b$ must be before $c$" mean? Does it mean that each time there's a $c$, there must be a $b$ immediately before it? or just somewhere before it? or does it mean each time there's a $b$, it must be followed immediately by a $c$? or what? Anyway, your $f_2$ seems wrong, as you haven't coounted $aa$, $bb$, and I think your $f_1$ is wrong, too, depending on what $b$ before $c$ means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is written here 'b' must be before 'c'. and c can be the first in the series.

Comment: So I can also add $ca,cb,$, and with $aa,bb$ I will have a total of $7$ options.

Comment: Still not clear whether it means "if there's a $b$, it must be immediately before a $c$", or "if there's a $c$, there must be a $b$ immediately before it". So it's not clear whether $bbc$ is allowed, or whether $bcc$ is allowed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let's assume that $bbc$ is allowed and $bcc$ are allowed too. (because $b$ is generally before $c$). How can I write my $f^n$ equation?

Comment: @mrprottolo I got it by saying that, if we start with $a$ we can have any $n-1$ valid series left. which adds to $f_{n-1}$ , the same with $b$. which makes it now $2f_{n-1}$. And now I see that with my edit, the series can also start with $c$. which makes it $f^n = 3f_{n-1}$ which is kinda weird..

Comment: @GerryMyerson If the solution is simpler when $b$ must be immediately before $c$, then, it is the way I need to go.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the condition on $b$ and $c$. A few comments up, you write that $cb$ is OK, even though there's a $c$ with no $b$ before it, and a $b$ that isn't in front of any $c$. Please, take some time to think it through, and when you can explain exactly what you mean, edit the body of your question so it gives an unambiguous statement of the condition.